# Why do you use reactjs children props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.js

```
import Header from "./header";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Header.js

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Header;
```

The code that was applied using "children props"

App.js

```
import Header from "./header";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </Header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Header.js

```
const Header = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Header;
```

I think I can just make it using 'props', so what is the reason for using 'children props'?

Comment: logically, you are doing it right. If you want to use the word props instead of children, Its okay. But it is not a suggested convention as the word props is being used to send and receive data between components by almost every developer. As you will grow with time and work on production application, to remain synced with other developers conventions, using 'children' is the suggested way and it also makes more sense to the reader(developer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern of HTML is very familiar to us.

```
<select>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

The thing is, this pattern shows the **hierarchy** of our components. In the same way in React, you can expose your component's hierarchy by `children`.

```
const Header = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Header;
```

You can paint the same HTML with props of course, but this way is more `declarative`. As you can assume that anything wrapped by `Header` component will treat as `children`.

One more advantage of using `children` is that it can give you more reusability. You can find more information about [composition in the official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

Answer (score 0):

props.children is a special prop, automatically passed to every component, that can be used to render the content included between the opening and closing tags when invoking a component.
You can code it like this

```
const Header = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};
```

or

```
const Header = ({children}) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};
```

This might be helpful: https://codeburst.io/a-complete-guide-to-props-children-in-react-c315fab74e7c

Comment: I wrote it wrong, I corrected it again.

Answer (score 0):

We sometimes use props or children to pass in values of strings, integers, boolean or etc. This helps to reduce the number of lines in one file and to make your code more readable.

The most important element is that you can reuse this component in your project. Reusability components save you time and extra lines of code.

I usually create reusable components for buttons, layouts, displays, Image Slider and etc. Below is the sample taken from you, but I've added children as props to accept any children's attributes.

```
const Header = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Header;
```